# What's the best way to retrieve data from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, instruments

My app stores current login user id to NSUserDefaults, and in a `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method I have to bind this id to every custom cell. I use `Instruments` to do analysis and find it cost too much time. 
So, my question is: is there cross-viewController approach to cache it after the first retrieve?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please also post the code of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. `NSUserDefaults` is slow on first load but it should be fast on later access. To improve you can store the ID in the property of the table and the cell. And when you reuse the cell, assign the ID from the table to the cell.

Comment: Use an ivar to store the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store your String `uid` from `NSUserDefaults` in `viewDidLoad()`, like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad() {
    ....
    uid  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].objectforKey:UD_USER_ID]
```

}

And the you can use `uid` string in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath` Method. It will not going to get fresh value for `UD_USER_ID` from `NSUserDefaults` as many time this method calls.

Comment: Is there any cross-viewController approach?

Comment: cross-viewController approach? can you elaborate further?

Comment: I mean A wrapper of NSUserDefaults with cache feature. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value.` from [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) , so it would be better to not wrap it and directly use it.

Comment: @Allen If I'm not mistaken, `NSUserDefaults` dose cache by default. That's probably why it's so expensive in the first place. Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it too much.